# Docker Compose with shell environment variable error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running a Docker deployment for an application. I'm mounting a volume where I want the external path to be provided by a shell environment variable. I get this error:

> ERROR: for video-server  Cannot create container for service video-server: invalid volume specification: '46b9d2fb3b9b13c9404d31bae571dac3f633122393c4a77f2561afb8aed5c06e:=/opt/videos:rw': invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: '=/opt/videos' mount path must be absolute

My docker-compose configuration is this:

```
video-server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: video-server_Dockerfile
    container_name: video-server
    networks:
      - videoManagerNetwork
    environment:
      - VIDEO_MANAGER_DIR=/opt/videos
    volumes:
      - ${VIDEO_MANAGER_DIR_PROD}=/opt/videos
    ports:
      - 9000:8080
```

I can see the correct value of the VIDEO_MANAGER_DIR_PROD environment variable by doing both of these commands, so I know it's on my shell:

```
echo $VIDEO_MANAGER_DIR_PROD
sudo echo $VIDEO_MANAGER_DIR_PROD
```

What's strange is that, if I do a complete wipe of my docker configurations (`sudo docker system prune --all --volumes`), and then run the docker-compose for the first time (`sudo docker-compose up -d`), everything works.

However, if I take the container down, rebuild it, and try to run that same command (`sudo docker-compose up -d`) again, then I get the error displayed above.

Comment: Is the host path an absolute path (does it start with `/`)?  There should be a `:` after it, not an `=`, in the `volumes:` specification.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign the source volume like a variable, so you will use `:` for this assignment.

Documentation about Docker Compose `volumes`: [docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes)

```
video-server:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: video-server_Dockerfile
  container_name: video-server
    networks:
      - videoManagerNetwork
    environment:
      - VIDEO_MANAGER_DIR: /opt/videos
    volumes:
      - ${VIDEO_MANAGER_DIR_PROD}:/opt/videos
    ports:
      - 9000:8080
```